# Dynamically Resize Image Within Table

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I'd like to dynamically resize images within a table I have made as the size of the browser changes resolution. At the moment if the browser is made small it makes the other columns very small/impractical or cuts off a column entirely.

Here is a JSFiddle of my table HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/zc2m9wq3/

I've already tried code like:`<img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:300px; max-height:300px;" src="...">` what I found though is max-width and max-height does not seem to work. The image just goes to its full resolution.

If someone could give me some guidance I would greatly appreciate it. I can also post my HTML and CSS here instead of just JSFiddle if required.
Thank you.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly?  Does this style `width:100%; min-width:100px;` on the img tag achieve what you're looking for? You can ignore the height style -- it should scale proportionately.

Comment: I tried that and it makes the image go to full resolution which is like over 1000x1000px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typically two ways.

First is set your image size **percent**

like this.

```
<img src="..." style="width:100%; height:auto; min-width:(what you want)">
```

Second is use **media query**. (actually upgrade from first way)

example(**CSS**)

```
img{ width:100%; height:auto; }
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    img{width:90%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    img{width:80%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    img{width:70%;}
}
```

you can use what you want

Thanks

Comment: Legend! Thanks for that, second way works perfectly just what I was after!